# Using image_filter to return both images and non-image files

Tags: nginx

I've configured nginx to [`image_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) the requests

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        index index.html;
        image_filter_buffer 20M;
        image_filter_jpeg_quality 75; # Desired JPG quality
        image_filter_interlace on; # For progressive JPG
        image_filter resize $arg_width $arg_height;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

but the location contains BOTH images and other files (such as pdf, html, ...).
Of course image_filter returns `415` when requested with a non-image content such as for example:

```
curl http://localhost/123456
```

where `123456` is a pdf file (saved with no *extension*) (*).

How can I have all the files returned without changing the directory structure?

(*) Well do not blame me: this is an over-simplified example, in the real world I have no files but proxied requests where the only known thing is the resource ID: no extension, no file type, nothing.
The actual configuration is:

```
location ~ /api/receipt-files/content/(.*)?$ {
    error_page 404 /empty-receipt.png;
    image_filter_buffer 20M;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality 75; # Desired JPG quality
    image_filter_interlace on; # For progressive JPG
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api/receipt-files/content/$1?$args;
    image_filter resize $arg_width $arg_height;
}
```

this works perfectly for images but fails with [`415`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) when for example `/api/receipt-files/content` returns an `appplication/pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

Confine the `image_filter` to a regex `location` that matches only files with an image extension. For example:

```
location ~ \.(jpg|gif|png|webp)$ {
    ....
}
```

Comment: It would we a good solution except that in the real world I do not have files but requests proxied to an application where the only known parameter is the numerical ID of the requested resource. I've clarified this in the question

Comment: @lrkwz Are these actually static files on your filesystem?

Comment: no those are resources fetched from an api

Comment: Why isn't the application doing the image resizing, then?

Comment: Because as I sayed there can be images AND pdf, doc etc etc, those files when requested cause a 415 http code.

Comment: That's about nginx, but you said you have an API. What is really going on here?

Comment: Sorry as I said in the question "this is an over-simplified example, in the real world I have no files but proxied requests where the only known thing is the resource ID: no extension, no file type, nothing." am I unclear? Thant only to say than I need a nginx solution , no file-rename or thas sort  of workaround

Comment: @lrkwz OK, but your new text doesn't match your nginx configuration, which describes a config for a website with only static files, and no API. So it's still confusing. nginx can only do this for static files.

Comment: Added even the API configuration (it add's no more info in my opinion but you are right it is more fair).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90311/discussion-between-lrkwz-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: @lrkwz That makes it a completely different question, so it should have been added originally. It also means the answer is it is not possible. nginx can only image resize static files. You API application will have to do the image resizing.

Comment: Sorry, not true, image_filter works perfectly on the images returned by proxy-ed.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround found so far consists in modifying the front-end so that non-images requests are routed through a `location` with no `image_filter`.

I don't like much this solution because depends on changes in the html.